# R Error when adressing time series (ts) object instead of data.frame

Tags: r, function, time-series

I want to use a time series object (because I want to use lag() later) but I am not able to adress the time series object in a function:

With a data.frame it does not matter whether I code

```
dat=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
sum(2*dat[,"x"])

[1] 42
```

or alternatively

```
with(dat,sum(2*x))

[1] 42
```

But as soon as I transform the data.frame into a time series object the function does not work anymore.

```
dat=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
dat <- ts(dat)
sum(2*dat[,"x"])

[1] 42
```

so this still works, but

```
with(dat,sum(2*x))
```

now results in an

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
```

Or to put it in other words: 
With the ts-object I cannot use any functions like

```
testy <- function(data,par){
  with(data,sum(par * x))
}
sapply(data=dat,2,testy)
```

without getting that error "numeric 'envir' arg not of length one" whereas df-objects do not cause that error. But I need ts() later for the lag() function.

What can I do to use time series objects within a function?

Comment: It is not a data.frame after the `ts`

Comment: If you check the `methods(class = 'zoo')` it can use `with`.  So, converting it to `zoo` may be an option `with(zoo(dat), sum(2 * x))#
[1] 42`

Answer (score 0):

We could convert it to `zoo` and it has `with` as one of its `methods`

```
library(zoo)
methods(class = 'zoo')
with(zoo(dat), sum(2 * x))
# [1] 42
```